# how do I convert the first part of JSON into an array python?

Tags: python, json

example

```
{'1':'e1','2':'e2','3':'e3'}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to isolate the name of the variables into an array of ['1','2','3'], in python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `list(d)`

```
d = {'1':'e1','2':'e2','3':'e3'}

print(list(d)) # -> ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

In python: if `d = {'1':'e1','2':'e2','3':'e3'}`, then `list(d.keys())` will give you `['1', '2', '3']`.